# How to make the scanner understand the amount I write?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is just some homework but I cannot find a way to achieve it like I want. Have a look at my code please.
Once the numbers are typed, I'd just like to play around with them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //user says if he'd like to use 3 numbers for instance (2,4,5)
    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to use? : ");
    int amountOfNumbers = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Great! Please type in your numbers: ");
    int numbers =sc.nextInt(amountOfNumbers);
    // should let him write the amount of numbers he entered    
}
```

Once he has typed the amount of numbers he'd like to use, I would like the scanner to give him the possibility to type in all of those numbers.

Let's say he the amount of numbers he'd like to use is three.
I would like him to be able to type it in the console like this:

- First number + enter key
- Second number + enter key
- Third number + enter key
- Not able to write anymore

That is what I meant here by adding "amountOfNumbers" in the scanner itself... (which is not working)

```
int numbers =sc.nextInt(amountOfNumbers);
```

BR

Comment: I am pretty sure that you are not wanting this method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: I agree with @ScaryWombat. Probably you are learning to use Scanner and just trying the methods. But this method doesn't do what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: As far as I've understood it, I do need it for amountOfNumbers. But not for "numbers"...

Comment: @Djabone I think the [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*; 
class EnterNumber{

    public void enter_list_function(){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to use?"); 

        //Enter the Numbers of amount
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Great! Please type in your numbers: "); 
        //Input - Numbers of amount
        for(int j =1; j<=input; j++ ){
            int addval = sc.nextInt();
            //Add the enter amount in array
            list.add(addval);

        }

        Iterator itr=list.iterator();  
        while(itr.hasNext()){  
           //get the enter amount from list
           System.out.println(itr.next());  
        }  
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        EnterNumber EnterNumber = new EnterNumber();
        EnterNumber.enter_list_function();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < amountofNumbers; i++){
    // add to a collection / array / list
}
```

And then access what you need from there.

Comment: I can't really make a connection, I'm quite new to programming... My main issue is how could I let the user write two times, if he decides to the amount of numbers he'd like is two numbers.